# laravel queue:work with priority if it exists

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs, priority-queue, worker

I need my Laravel workers to work with a queue priority, in Laravel documentation it is achieved by using:

```
php artisan work:queue --queue=jobA,jobB
```

Running this, all jobs with the queue **jobA** will dispatched, and then the ones with **jobB**, but what I need to do is prioritize the jobs with queue **jobA**, but when there is not more of this jobs remaining, dispatch any of the remaining jobs.
I need this in order to make sure that all my workers are being used, because if I have 50 jobs with the queue **jobD**, and none with the queue **jobA**, I want that worker to keep working with those remaining while there is none of **jobA**, something like:

```
php artisan work:queue --queue=jobA,jobB,[anyOtherJobRemaining]
```

Where the worker will dispatch all the jobs with queue **jobA**, then **jobB**, and then any other available job in the jobs table.
What I'm trying to do here is to optimize the way I use the workers, or if there is a better way to achieve this it would be really nice if anyone can point me to the solution. Thank you!

Comment: You may be overusing the queues. Normally you'd have a finite number of predetermined queues which you can prioritise explicitly

Comment: Sure, but if I count with 8 workers, I want them all to be working while there is at least one job available, but always the same 8 workers, just (as an example) I want two workers to prioritize A, two for B, two for C, and two for D, if there are not queues for A, then that worker should try to dispatch any job remaining. This way all queues will always have workers on it and all workers can really be used

Comment: I guess you can have workers 1 and 2 process all queues in order, then workers 3 and 4 process all except the top 2 etc etc

Comment: Thank you for answering again! Yes, I could use something like php artisan work:queue --queue=jobA,jobB,jobC,etc... And it would work just fine like that, but I would have to specify any new queue plus all the others every time I need to use this...it feels like it should be a way  to accomplish this. For example if the other queues were created by default I would just use php artisan work:queue --queue=jobA, and it would work like that, But the problem is the other jobs also have a different queue.

Comment: You can probably create a script that generates your supervisor config (or whatever you use to persist your queue worker) based on a list of queues you have. Other than that I don't think there's anything that's already implemented in Laravel that will help you with your use case since it seems pretty uncommon